# update linkbutton text dynamically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change the text for the link-button dynamically based on if the user is logged in or not.  The text should be Log-out if user is logged in and vice versa.  It is always showing Login.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
 <p><asp:LinkButton ID="MyLnkButton" runat="server" EnableViewState = "False" onClick="MyLnkButton_Click" Text="" ForeColor="Red"/></p>
```

code behind

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
       if (Session["USRID"] != null)
       {
            lblWLC.Text = (string)Session["USRID"];                   
            MyLnkButton.Text = "Logout";
            Bind_GV();
       }
       else 
            MyLnkButton.Text = "Login";
 }
```

Comment: I would also remove the following to resolve the issue `EnableViewState = "False"` here is some reading that can show you alternatives to the following you are experiencing as well https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i just added that just now to see if that helps but it seems with or without it; it does not work

Comment: I would suggest stepping thru the code.. and checking the `IsPostBack` when setting a breakpoint to see if it's `true` if so then you should know what the issue is .. add code that says `if(IsPostBack){}else{}` your logic is almost correct please let me know if my interpretation of what you want is correct in my provided answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reverse the logic question is do you need to call `Bind_GV` regardless of post back.. if so I will depict in my code below

```
if (Page.IsPostBack && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["USRID"]))
{
    MyLnkButton.Text = "Login";
}
else
{
    lblWLC.Text = (string)Session["USRID"];                   
    MyLnkButton.Text = "Logout";
    Bind_GV();
}
```

Comment: i only want to call Bind_GV if session is not null

Comment: yep.. I love it when a plan comes to light... glad I could quickly see where you were going wrong.. you're welcome..